# How to use TCP-based HTTP to download image in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

How to use TCP-based HTTP to download image in python? I do download the image but it says cannot open this file( which probably means not all of the bytes were recv or written). My task is to use socket library and no urlib or requests.
Any help is appreciated.

```
serverPort = 80
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect(('google.com', serverPort))
print("ready to receive!")

output = 'GET  http://google.com/favicon.ico HTTP/1.0\r\nHOST: google.com\r\n\r\n'
print(output)
output1 = ('b' + output)
clientSocket.sendall(output1.encode())
reply = b''

while True:
    data = clientSocket.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    reply += data

headers = reply.split(b'\r\n\r\n')[0]
image = reply[len(headers) + 4:]

f = open('image_test.ico', 'wb')
f.write(image)
f.close()

clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: You are doing HTTP with  socket? RLY? Use a library like `requests`.

Comment: Yeah, its an requirement to use socket.

Comment: Then add that requirement to your question and explain why you have that requirement since it is very strange.

Comment: HTTP uses TCP as its underlying transport protocol by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating a byte object by adding `'b'` to the beginning of a string.  You are mixing Python's representation with the actual contents.

```
b'bytes'
```

is a sequence of `bytes` where each element is guaranteed to be a single 8-bit byte corresponding to the ASCII code of the character.

```
'b' + 'bytes'
```

is a Unicode string where each element is not guaranteed to be a single byte, but rather, a Python character.  It is equivalent to

```
'bbytes'
```

or (to be really explicit)

```
u'bbytes'
```

The `b` or `u` prefix is a signal to the Python interpreter for how the sequence should be stored, not part of the value.

To convert a string to a `bytes` object, call the string's `encode` method.

```
output1 = b'bytes'.encode('us-ascii')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
import socket
import select

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('google.com', 80))
s.sendall(b'GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')

reply = b''

while select.select([s], [], [], 3)[0]:
    data = s.recv(2048)
    if not data: break
    reply += data

headers =  reply.split(b'\r\n\r\n')[0]
image = reply[len(headers)+4:]

# save image
f = open('google.ico', 'wb')
f.write(image)
f.close()
```

Comment: I found your similar solution in some other thread as well, this code of yours works perfectly fine. But when i use this s.sendall(b'GET  http://google.com/favicon.ico HTTP/1.0\r\nHOST: google.com\r\n\r\n') it doesn't download the image completely ! can you help me with this

Comment: Try out the updated code and open the .ico file in your browser.

Comment: can you explain me what does this do 'select.select([s], [], [], 3)[0]:'?

Comment: what if i try to download it on http1.1? , it get stuck!

Comment: In HTTP1.1 the server will not close the connection and will be waiting for more requests but in HTTP1.0 the connection will be closed after the request is done and transfer of data is done.